# TypeScript: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript

I am having an issue with my function:

```
    copyObject<T> (object:T):T {
        var objectCopy = <T>{};
        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                objectCopy[key] = object[key];
            }
        }
        return objectCopy;
    }
```

And I have following error:

```
Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think it's because of the `var key in object` and the usage of `key` afterwards. Can you try to run the compilation with `noImplicitAny=false` to confirm?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
class test<T> {
    copyObject<T> (object:T):T {
        var objectCopy = <T>{};
        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                objectCopy[key] = object[key];
            }
        }
        return objectCopy;
    }
}
```

If I run the code as follows

```
c:\Work\TypeScript>tsc hello.ts
```

it works OK. However, the following code:

```
c:\Work\TypeScript>tsc --noImplicitAny hello.ts
```

throws

```
hello.ts(6,17): error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
hello.ts(6,35): error TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

So if you disable `noImplicitAny` flag, it will work.

There seems to be another option as well because `tsc` supports the following flag:

```
--suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors   Suppress noImplicitAny errors for indexing objects lacking index signatures.
```

This works for me too:

```
tsc --noImplicitAny --suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors hello.ts
```

**Update:**

```
class test<T> {
    copyObject<T> (object:T):T {
        let objectCopy:any = <T>{};
        let objectSource:any = object;
        for (var key in objectSource) {
            if (objectSource.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                objectCopy[key] = objectSource[key];
            }
        }
        return objectCopy;
    }
}
```

This code works without changing any compiler flags.

Comment: Hi Martin, great answer to the question, I was just wondering if you (or anyone else) know why this works, or why we have to define the local objectCopy and objectSource variables?

Comment: Heads up: The reason why the error is being thrown is because the object you're trying to copy might have more properties on it than you want it to. There is a lot of information inside the Github repo for TypeScript. I realize that the errors are not obvious though. This might help? https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14951#issuecomment-392111183

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late, but in the current version of TypeScript (maybe ver 2.7 and newer), you can write it like below.

```
for (var key in object) {
    if (objectSource.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const k = key as keyof typeof object;
        objectCopy[k] = object[k]; // object and objectCopy need to be the same type
    }
}
```